# Include the contents of a file in a Vue template without using a child component

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue component that contains some template sections that I want to reuse in some new components. These new components share the functionality of the original component via a mixin.

I am aware that one option would be to turn each of the template sections I want to reuse into a component itself. However, if I do this then I'll need to write a heap of new code to handle passing all the variables down and the events back up (there's a lot of them). Really I want it to behave like it is part of the parent component; like a php `include()`.

Is there a straight forward way of doing this with Vue?

I'm using webpack (which came bundled with Laravel and I confess to not knowing an awful lot about) to compile the code, so I wonder if there is some way of doing it with that rather than with Vue itself.

Comment: Re-write the code. Instead of complex parent>child relationships, use a global event bus so you can avoid this in the future.

Comment: Can you give a example of your code and which bits you don't want to loose? It's a little hard to fully understand what you mean otherwise :)